# checking network bandwidth with iperf

Tags: networking, bandwidth, throughput, iperf

I am  trying to  measure network  bandwidth with iPerf:
I opened a server on my PC (-s)  and used another laptop as a client(-c ip_address -P N),  it worked  well with  1,10,100 clients (I simulated multiple clients through -P N (N- number of clients)). However, when  I increased  N to 150 I got some errors like 'Connection reset by peer' or 'Connection timed out'. My question is that what is the difference between simulating a number of devices as a client and using real devices as a client while checking the network bandwidth with Iperf.
Thank  you

Comment: I have been attempting to reproduce the error messages you have received, but have been unable to. Could you please specify the version of iperf you are using? Creating an output log on the client specifying the '-o' tag on the command could also help identify the issue. Finally knowing the hardware from both client and server could also narrow down Why this happens, disk space or RAM could affect the number of connections; and Operating System from the server to identify if it might be caused by a compatibilty issue between iperf and the OS.

Comment: The bandwidth is from the network interface. For example, a 100Base-TX ethernet interface always has a bandwidth of 100 Mbps. What you seem to try to measure is the throughput, which is very different than the bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to increase the number of file descriptors as [described here for linux.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/)

Also, it's a good idea to use [iperf 2.1.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf2/).  Finally, -P N is not simulating clients. For iperf 2 it uses threads to create multiple traffic threads and iperf 3 uses processes.